# calculate mean for each cell in grid in R

Tags: r, raster, spatial-data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sliding window function in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931706/sliding-window-function-in-r)

This might be a silly question, but I couldn't find an answer so far.
I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(lat = (-10: 10),
                 lon = (-10: 10),
                 A = runif(21, 1 ,10),
                 B = runif(21, 20 ,30))
```

where lat and lon are geographic coordinates, and A  and B are two continuos variables.
What I would like to do, is to create a 5 by 5 grid and calculate the mean value of A and B within each cell of the grid. Here is the approach I'm trying but with no success...

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)

coordinates(df) <- ~ lat + lon
rast <- raster(ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
extent(rast) <- extent(df)
rasterize(df, rast, df$A, fun = mean)
```

Comment: You're looking for the `focal()` function in the **raster** package: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9931706/sliding-window-function-in-r/9933326#9933326

Comment: Thanks Josh, thats should do.

Comment: We should either close this as a duplicate or matteo should finish this with an answer based on his new knowledge. Everyone should go to the link and upvote Josh's useful answer while they are at it.

Comment: ok DWin, can be closed, I'm happy with the solution pointed out by Josh, and I've up-voted his other post.