# R data.table sliding window

Tags: r, time-series, data.table, sliding-window

What is the best (fastest) way to implement a sliding window function with the data.table package?

I'm trying to calculate a rolling median but have multiple rows per date (due to 2 additional factors), which I think means that the zoo rollapply function wouldn't work. Here is an example using a naive for loop:

```
library(data.table)
df <- data.frame(
  id=30000,
  date=rep(as.IDate(as.IDate("2012-01-01")+0:29, origin="1970-01-01"), each=1000),
  factor1=rep(1:5, each=200),
  factor2=1:5,
  value=rnorm(30, 100, 10)
)

dt = data.table(df)
setkeyv(dt, c("date", "factor1", "factor2"))

get_window <- function(date, factor1, factor2) {
  criteria <- data.table(
    date=as.IDate((date - 7):(date - 1), origin="1970-01-01"),
    factor1=as.integer(factor1),
    factor2=as.integer(factor2)
  )
  return(dt[criteria][, value])
}

output <- data.table(unique(dt[, list(date, factor1, factor2)]))[, window_median:=as.numeric(NA)]

for(i in nrow(output):1) {
  print(i)
  output[i, window_median:=median(get_window(date, factor1, factor2))]
}
```

Comment: +1 too. Can you provide more info about data size and times. From your comment to Alan's answer (alan and Alan are different people?), it takes 6.4s (vs 973s for `data.frame`) and you'd like to improve 6.4s further?

Comment: Alan and alan are different people :). The dataset has ~650,000 rows. I came up with a solution that works much faster but is very memory intensive. Any ideas on how it can be improved further?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`data.table` doesn't have any special features for rolling windows, currently. Further detail here in my answer to another similar question here :

[Is there a *fast* way to run a rolling regression inside data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12157723/403310)

Rolling median is interesting. It would need a specialized function to do efficiently (same link as in earlier comment) :

[Rolling median algorithm in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309263/rolling-median-algorithm-in-c?lq=1)

The `data.table` solutions in the question and answers here are all very inefficient, relative to a proper specialized `rollingmedian` function (which isn't available for R afaik).

Comment: @MusX Ok I've upped the priority to top.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get the example down to 1.4s by creating a lagged dataset and doing a huge join.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=30000,
  date=rep(as.IDate(as.IDate("2012-01-01")+0:29, origin="1970-01-01"), each=1000),
  factor1=rep(1:5, each=200),
  factor2=1:5,
  value=rnorm(30, 100, 10)
)

dt2 <- data.table(df)
setkeyv(dt, c("date", "factor1", "factor2"))

unique_set <-  data.table(unique(dt[, list(original_date=date, factor1, factor2)]))
output2 <- data.table()
for(i in 1:7) {
  output2 <- rbind(output2, unique_set[, date:=original_date-i])
}    

setkeyv(output2, c("date", "factor1", "factor2"))
output2 <- output2[dt]
output2 <- output2[, median(value), by=c("original_date", "factor1", "factor2")]
```

That works pretty well on this test dataset but on my real one it fails with 8GB of RAM. I'm going to try moving up to one of the High Memory EC2 instance (with 17, 34 or 68GB RAM) to get it working. Any ideas on how to do this in a less memory intensive way would be appreciated

Comment: Just on first glance, the `rbind` inside the `for` will be using too much RAM. Must be a more direct way to do that bit.

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309263/rolling-median-algorithm-in-c) mentions binary search, R and C for rolling median. Looks promising for you to investigate further; i.e., think about the _algorithm_.

Answer (score 1):

I address this in a related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62399700/7115566

I suggest looking into the `frollapply` function. For instance, see below

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(17)
dt <- data.table(i = 1:100,
             x = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T),
             y = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T))
dt$index <- dt$x == dt$y
dt[,`:=` (MA = frollapply(index,10,mean)), ]
head(dt,12)
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution works but it takes a while.

```
df <- data.frame(
  id=30000,
  date=rep(seq.Date(from=as.Date("2012-01-01"),to=as.Date("2012-01-30"),by="d"),each=1000),
  factor1=rep(1:5, each=200),
  factor2=1:5,
  value=rnorm(30, 100, 10)
)

myFun <- function(dff,df){
    median(df$value[df$date>as.Date(dff[2])-8 & df$date<as.Date(dff[2])-1 & df$factor1==dff[3] & df$factor2==dff[4]])
}

week_Med <- apply(df,1,myFun,df=df)

week_Med_df <- cbind(df,week_Med)
```

Comment: Thanks! It seems to take longer than the for loop though. The timings I'm getting from system.time are 973s for your code 6.4s for the loop. I think the difference must be the use of the data.table package