# using data.table to speed up rollapply

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, apply, xts

I am new to data.tables so apologies if this is a very basic question.

I have heard that data.tables significantly improves computational times when working with large amounts  data, and so would like to see if data.table is able to help in speeding up the rollapply function.

if we have some univariate data

```
xts.obj <- xts(rnorm(1e6), order.by=as.POSIXct(Sys.time()-1e6:1), tz="GMT") 
colnames(xts.obj) <- "rtns"
```

a simple rolling quantile with width of 100 and a p of 0.75 takes a surprisingly long time...

i.e. the line of code

```
xts.obj$quant.75 <- rollapply(xts.obj$rtns,width=100, FUN='quantile', p=0.75)
```

seems to take forever...

is there anything that data.table can do to speed things up? i.e. is there a generic roll function that can be applied?

perhaps a routine to convert an xts object to a data.table object to carry out the function in a speeded up manner and then reconvert back to xts at the end?

thanks in advance

hlm

p.s. I didn't seem to be getting much of a response on the data.table mailing list so am posting up here, to see if I get a better response.

p.p.s having a quick go with another example using dataframes the data.table solution seems to take longer than the rollapply function, i.e. shown below:

```
> x <- data.frame(x=rnorm(10000))
> x.dt <- data.table(x)
> system.time(l1 <- as.numeric(rollapply(x,width=10,FUN=quantile,p=0.75)))   
   user  system elapsed 
   2.69    0.00    2.68 
> system.time(l <- as.numeric(unlist(x.dt[,lapply(1:((nrow(x.dt))-10+1), function(i){ x.dt[i:(i+10-1),quantile(x,p=0.75)]})])))
   user  system elapsed 
  11.22    0.00   11.51 
> identical(l,l1)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Not much response from datatable-help? You didn't even wait 1 day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

datatable is quite irrelevant here - you're essentially running `sapply` on a vector, that is pretty much the fastest operation you can get (other than going to C). data frames and data tables will always be slower than vectors. You can gain a bit by using a straight vector (without xts dispatch), but the only easy way to get this done quickly is to parallelize:

```
> x = as.vector(xts.obj$rtns)
> system.time(unclass(mclapply(1:(length(x) - 99),
                      function(i) quantile(x[i:(i + 99)], p=0.75), mc.cores=32)))
   user  system elapsed 
325.481  15.533  11.221
```

If you need that even faster, then you may want to write a specialized function: the naive apply approach re-sorts every chunk which is obviously wasteful - all you need to do is to drop the one element and sort in the next one to obtain the quantile so you can expect roughly 50x speedup if you do that - but you'll have to code that yourself (so it's only worth if you use it more often ...).

Comment: And that specialized function appears to be detailed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1309263/rolling-median-algorithm-in-c). Btw, `data.table` is faster than `*apply`, though, because of FAQ 3.1 point 2 (it allocates once for the largest group and reuses that, unlike `*apply`). That might be why we see questions asking if `data.table` tackles `rollapply`, too (e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676476/r-data-table-sliding-window)). But rolling quantile is quite different because of the sorting aspect.

Answer (score 5):

`data.table` works quickly by splitting the data by a key. I don't think `data.table` currently supports a rolling key, or an expression that in the `by` or `i` arguments that would do this.

You could use the fact that subsetting is faster for `data.table` than a `data.frame`

```
DT <- as.data.table(x)
.x <- 1:(nrow(DT)-9)
system.time(.xl <- unlist(lapply(.x, function(.i) DT[.i:(.i+10),quantile(x,0.75, na.rm = T)])))
   user  system elapsed 
   8.77    0.00    8.77
```

Or you could construct key variables that will uniquely identify the rolling ids. Width = 10, therefore we need 10 columns (padded with `NA_real_`)

```
library(plyr) # for as.quoted
.j <- paste0('x',1:10, ':= c(rep(NA_real_,',0:9,'),rep(seq(',1:10,',9991,by=10),each=10), rep(NA_real_,',c(0,9:1),'))')


 datatable <- function(){
   invisible(lapply(.j, function(.jc) x.dt[,eval(as.quoted(.jc)[[1]])]))
x_roll <- rbind(x.dt[!is.na(x1),quantile(x,0.75),by=x1],
  x.dt[!is.na(x2),quantile(x,0.75),by=x2],
  x.dt[!is.na(x3),quantile(x,0.75),by=x3],
  x.dt[!is.na(x4),quantile(x,0.75),by=x4],
      x.dt[!is.na(x5),quantile(x,0.75),by=x5],
      x.dt[!is.na(x6),quantile(x,0.75),by=x6],
      x.dt[!is.na(x7),quantile(x,0.75),by=x7],
      x.dt[!is.na(x8),quantile(x,0.75),by=x8],
      x.dt[!is.na(x9),quantile(x,0.75),by=x9],
      x.dt[!is.na(x10),quantile(x,0.75),by=x10],use.names =F)


setkeyv(x_roll,'x1')

invisible(x.dt[,x1:= 1:10000])
setkeyv(x.dt,'x1')
x_roll[x.dt][, list(x,V1)]}

l1 <- function()as.numeric(rollapply(x,width=10,FUN=quantile,p=0.75))
lapply_only <- function() unclass(lapply(1:(nrow(x) - 9), function(i) quantile(x[['x']][i:(i + 9)], p=0.75)))


benchmark(datatable(),l1(),lapply_only(), replications = 5)
##            test replications elapsed relative user.self 
## 1   datatable()            5    9.41 1.000000      9.40      
## 2          l1()            5   10.97 1.165781     10.85        
## 3 lapply_only()            5   10.39 1.104145     10.35
```

### EDIT --- benchmarking

`data.table` is quicker than rollapply and raw lapply. I can't test the parallel solution.

Comment: Thanks for that...shame that the improvement in speed wasn't greater than 16%, I was kinda hoping for orders of magnitude, in terms of speed by using data.tables. Simon's solution does indeed provide orders of magnitude speed improvements, but I wonder if there is a way to combine them?

Comment: @h.l.m You should be able to place Simon's call to `mclapply` inside `j` of data.table, if that helps. But essentially, fully efficient rolling quantile isn't available in R, afaik - see links I commented to Simon's answer.

Comment: FWIW you are creating artificial inefficiencies in your code -- missing the vector aspect. See my answer - it will give you clues why your version is slower. If you are willing to throw memory at it (which you do with `data.table`) there is a faster, one-line solution (hint: apply on a matrix) but they all are within a few percent and for large widths you'll need a lot of memory.  BTW - good luck with copy/paste - the original question has `width=100` ;).