# Is it possible to compute any window join in data.table

Tags: r, join, data.table

I came across a lot of posts asking about window joins

1. [rolling median](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676476/r-data-table-sliding-window)
2. [rolling regression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139934/is-there-a-fast-way-to-run-a-rolling-regression-inside-data-table/12157723#12157723)

Since data.table `1.8.8` and the `roll` parameter my understanding is that we can do those things. Say we have `X` and `Y` with same keys say `x,y,t`, we want to be able to get for each line of `X`

**all the rows of `Y` where `x,y` of `Y` are matching those of `X` AND where `X$t in [Y$t-w1,Y$t+w2]`**

Here is an example with `(w1,w2)=(1,5)`

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table(x=c(1,1,1,2,2),y=c(F,F,T,T,T),t=c(407,286,788,882,942),key='x,y,t')
X <- copy(A)
Y <- data.table(x=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2),y=c(F,F,T,T,T,T,T),u=c(417,285,788,882,941,942,945),IDX=1:7,key='x,y,u')
```

---

```
R) X
   x     y   t
1: 1 FALSE 286
2: 1 FALSE 407
3: 1  TRUE 788
4: 2  TRUE 882
5: 2  TRUE 942
R) Y
   x     y   u IDX
1: 1 FALSE 285   2 # match line 1 as (x,y) ok and 285 in [286-1,286+5]
2: 1 FALSE 417   1 # match no line as (x,y) ok against X[c(1,2),] but 417 is too big
3: 1  TRUE 788   3 # match row 3
4: 2  TRUE 882   4 # match row 4
5: 2  TRUE 941   5 # match row 5
6: 2  TRUE 942   6 # match row 5
7: 2  TRUE 945   7 # match row 5
```

---

We cannot do `Y[setkey(X[,list(x,y,t)],x,y,t),roll=1]` because if we have a perfect match on (x,y,t) data.table will discard potential partial matches with `X$t in [Y$t-w1,X$t[`.

```
#get the lower bounds and upper bounds for t
X[,`:=`(lowT=t-1,upT=t+5)]
#we get the first line where Y$u >= X$t-1 but Y$u <= X$t+5
X <- setnames(copy(Y),c('u','IDX'),c('lowT','lowIDX'))[setkey(X,x,y,lowT),roll=-6,rollends=T]
#we get the last line where Y$u <= X$t+5 ...
X <- setnames(copy(Y),c('u','IDX'),c('upT','upIDX'))[setkey(X,x,y,upT),roll=6]
#we get the matching IDX
X[!is.na(lowIDX) & !is.na(upIDX), allIDX:=mapply(`seq`,from=lowIDX,to=upIDX)]
```

---

```
R) X
   x     y upT upIDX lowT lowIDX   t allIDX
1: 1 FALSE 291     2  285      2 286      2
2: 1 FALSE 412    NA  406     NA 407       
3: 1  TRUE 793     3  787      3 788      3
4: 2  TRUE 887     4  881      4 882      4
5: 2  TRUE 947     7  941      5 942  5,6,7
```

My questions are:

1. Am I correct to think that window joins could not be achieve easily before `roll`?
2. Can we solve the pb if we want `X$t in ]Y$t-w1,Y$t+w2[` (not compact set anymore) ?