# R data table rolling unique

Tags: r, data.table, rolling-computation

Have been looking for a solution for counting unique values of a column in a data data table in a rolling fashion, found rollmean but have not found something like rollunique.

What is a good practice for achieving this using data table?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**1)** An option is to use `zoo::rollapply`

sample data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(0L)
sz <- 1e5L
winsz <- 5L
DT <- data.table(ID=sample(letters, sz, replace=TRUE))
```

sample usage using `zoo:rollapply*`:

```
DT[, numUniq := zoo::rollapplyr(ID, winsz, uniqueN, fill=NA_integer_)]
```

**2)** Another option is to write your own windowing:

```
DT[, numUniq2 := replace(
    sapply(1:.N, function(n) uniqueN(ID[max(n-winsz+1, 1L):n])),
    .I < winsz,
    NA_integer_)]
```

**3)** Another option is to use `data.table::shift`

```
DT[, numUniq3 := replace(
    apply(setDT(shift(ID, 0L:(winsz-1L))), 1L, uniqueN),
    1L:.N < winsz,
    NA_integer_)]
```

output:

```
        ID numUniq numUniq2 numUniq3
     1:  x      NA       NA       NA
     2:  g      NA       NA       NA
     3:  j      NA       NA       NA
     4:  o      NA       NA       NA
     5:  x       4        4        4
    ---                             
 99996:  k       4        4        4
 99997:  a       4        4        4
 99998:  f       4        4        4
 99999:  z       4        4        4
100000:  c       5        5        5
```

**Benchmarking**

timing code:

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    zooRoll=DT[, numUniq := zoo::rollapplyr(ID, winsz, uniqueN, fill=NA)],
    sapply=DT[, numUniq2 := replace(
        vapply(1L:.N, function(n) uniqueN(ID[max(n-winsz+1L, 1L):n]), integer(1L)),
        1L:.N < winsz,
        NA_integer_)],
    shift=DT[, numUniq3 := replace(
        apply(setDT(shift(ID, 0L:(winsz-1L))), 1L, uniqueN),
        1L:.N < winsz,
        NA_integer_)],
    times=3L)
```

timings:

```
Unit: seconds
    expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 zooRoll 1.723915 1.774423 1.837433 1.824931 1.894191 1.963451     3
  sapply 1.214608 1.224971 1.230763 1.235333 1.238840 1.242348     3
   shift 1.188266 1.234769 1.266852 1.281272 1.306145 1.331018     3
```

see also:

- [Is there a _fast_ way to run a rolling regression inside data.table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12139934/is-there-a-fast-way-to-run-a-rolling-regression-inside-data-table/12157723#12157723)
- [R data.table sliding window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676476/r-data-table-sliding-window/12214362#12214362)